# Recommendation for securing a external hard disk

Tags: security, hard-disk, data-recovery

I have lost dates (film files and docs) on my external hard disk with `dd` (hd was on `ext4` format, 2TB and had only videos and some files). I "restore"  them with **PhotoRec**, with bad quality... Because I will learn for my mistake, I will learn how to does an external hard disk safe.., so, next time, when similar mistake doing, can them to restore without problem and with gut quality....

For example, what recommend me for partition table, `MBR` or `GPT`?

Thanks you very much for your recommendations!

Comment: You applied the command `dd` to your drive?

Comment: yes, but  "restore" them with `PhotoRec`.., now i will learn how to do my external hard disk safe, when next Time, doing a mistake can restore it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Arch's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_recovery#List_of_utilities) you can find a list of utilities for recovery data. I recommend the use of `ext4magic` or `extundelete`, which are optimized for `ext`.

In turn, there are various tools to automate your backup like [tarsnap](https://www.tarsnap.com/) amd [restic](https://restic.net/).

Comment: Thanks!, I will learn with `restic`  I to try with `ext4magic` but without success.., how to say, I "restore" with **PhotoRec**, with very bad quality..Now download ALL my Film and Docus again....                                                             I wish you a nice Weenkend !

Answer (score 1):

When you ran `dd` as the root user you bypassed all the protections that the system gives you.

First, you increased your permissions from a normal user to the root account, which can do anything on the system. Second, you then used the `dd` utility, which cares nothing about its input or output, to write directly to your external disk.

While I'm sorry to hear that you have lost your data, the system is already secure provided you don't bypass the protections it offers you.

Pretty much the only other thing I can suggest is that in the future you backup your important data to second disk drive, or to somewhere away from your machine, and you make it a personal rule that you never, ever, have both the local disk and the remote backup connected at the same time.

Comment: very thanks for you recommendations, but give another possibility as `backup`? because i will stored to my external hard disk Film and the capacity is 2TB....

Comment: Use an external disk, but handle it correctly. And if it's not a backup (no other copies of the files), then make a backup.